# I can't figure out this XML parse and or string replace

Tags: c#

```
  <Screen>
    <ScreenContent>Random Text &lt;img style="height: 194px; width: 259px" alt="" src="C:\XXXXXXXXX\download.jpg" /&gt;&amp;nbsp;RANDOM TEXT &lt;img style="height: 194px; width: 259px" alt="" src="C:\XXXXXXXX\download1.jpg" /&gt;\
</ScreenContent>
  </Screen>
  <Screen>
    <ScreenContent>New Screen</ScreenContent>
  </Screen>
```

Here is a basic example of an XML document we are working with.

What I NEED to do is, in the first screen you will see two img's, the SRC of the images are listed as absolute paths, and I would like to parse the XML document and update the SRC for each image on each screen If it exists.

So for example:

```
img style="height: 194px; width: 259px" alt="" src="C:\XXXXXXXXX\download.jpg"
```

becomes:

```
img style="height: 194px; width: 259px" alt="" src="download.jpg"
```

There could be any amount of img's under each ScreenContent node.....

We can either accomplish this BEFORE we write the XML, or we can update the XML file after the fact.

If we do it before the XML is written, the screen content is saved as one long basic string.

I know about XML Node parsing, but the IMG's are not being saved as individual nodes so it is difficult for me to go that route

Comment: "If we do it before the XML is written, the screen content is saved as one long basic string" Huum? What does this mean? You should modify your **data**, not the xml-**representation**. How does the appropriate code look like?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for responding, it is a basic string and an example would be ----     RANDOM TEXT <img style="height: 194px; width: 259px" alt="" src="file:///C:/xxxxxxxxxxxx/download1.jpg" />  MORE RANDOM TEXT

----   There could technically be 15 images, not just one

Comment: I ment the code that writes that xml.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It is a basic DLL that reads a microsoft word like document.... The thing that writes it to the file is just a TextWriter and XmlSerializer. It loops through all the strings that we want to save and then serializes as XML

Comment: when you want to **manipulate** data, you should do so **before** writing it into some persistant store. There´s no point on writing first, reading, manipulating and writing again.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree, I could technically write some for loop that tries to find all instances of "img" in each string, then updates the src. I feel like that could get messy and be error prone.... Chopping up one big giant string and trying to replace individual components (while they still exist) Perhaps there is some sort of regex that would be useful?

Comment: `imageText.Replace("C:/XXXX", "")`?

Comment: Well that would be close to working, the absolute path to the image may be different, different machines / image locations. So I would have to parse the entire path to the image, remove all unneccesary characters, then go on to the next imagePath if it exists.

Comment: You may try to use the XDocument class.If you combine this with XPath search for the <ScreenContent> you just pick out that part, edit it as a text file and then put it back, save the XML. You probably need an XDocument tutorial before you can work with it, but I think it is worth the trouble if you work more often with XML files.